# How to update state of elements from array.map() separately?

Tags: reactjs, use-state

In my code, I am trying to retrieve background images depending on the background data on the object, however those backgrounds will also change depending on the state of the element.

First of all, my data array looks like this:

```
   const Cube = [
      {
         name: "foo"
         faces: [
            {
               data: [
                  [{bonus: "bar", bg: "bar2"}],
                  ...
               ],
               ...
            },
            ...
         ],
         ...
      },
      ...
   ];
```

And this is how my App.js looks:

```
  function App() {
    const [cellState, setCellState] = useState("inactive");

    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div id="cube-container">
          {Cube[0].faces[0].data.map((row) => {
            return row.map((cell, index) => {
              return (
                <img
                src={require(`./assets/cube/Square_Cube_Icon/${cell.bg}${
                  cellState === "inactive" ? "_Unlit" : "_Partial"
                }.png`)}
                alt={`${cell.bg} background`}
                className="cellItem"
                onClick={() => setCellState("active")}
                state={cellState}
                key={index}
              />
            );
          });
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Question is, in the 4x4 grid output, if I click on any item, instead of changing the clicked elements background because of state change, it changes background of every cell, which should happen since the useState is shared between all of them.
How can I make it so every element of the map function has their own state that I can update separately?

Found the solution:

Separating it as a component and passing key and cell values as props, then creating and manipulating the state inside fixed the issue.Selected answer also solves the issue.

Here's the solution for future readers.

App.js

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div id="cube-container">
        {CubeOfTruth[0].faces[0].data.map((row) => {
          return row.map((cell, index) => {
            return <CubeItem key={index} cell={cell} />;
          });
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

CubeItem.js

```
function CubeItem({ cell, index }) {
  const [cellState, setCellState] = useState("inactive");

  return (
    <img
      src={require(`../assets/cube/Square_Cube_Icon/${cell.bg}${
        cellState === "inactive" || cellState === "partial" ? "_Unlit" : ""
      }.png`)}
      alt={`${cell.bg} background`}
      className="cellItem"
      onClick={() => setCellState("active")}
      state={cellState}
      key={index}
    />
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an easy way to manage multiple states using an object with its keys representing your cells and the values representing whether it is active or inactive. This is also easy to generalize so if you add more cells then all you have to do is just add it to the initialState & rest of your code should work as is.

```
function App() {

   // const [cellState, setCellState] = useState("inactive");
    
    const initialState = {
      bar1: "inactive",
      bar2: "inactive",
      bar3: "inactive",
      bar4: "inactive",
    }

   const [cellState, SetCellState] = React.useState(initialState);

   const handleSetCellState = (key)  => {   
    setCellState({
     ...cellState,
     [key]: "active",
    });   
   }; 


    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div id="cube-container">
          {Cube[0].faces[0].data.map((row) => {
            return row.map((cell, index) => {
              return (
                <img
                src={require(`./assets/cube/Square_Cube_Icon/${cell.bg}${
                  cellState[cell.bg] === "inactive" ? "_Unlit" : "_Partial"
                }.png`)}
                alt={`${cell.bg} background`}
                className="cellItem"
                onClick={() => handleSetCellState(cell.bg)}
                state={cellState[cell.bg]}
                key={index}
              />
            );
          });
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid this doesn't seem to help in my situation. When I applied the given code, for example: If I click a cell with red background, every element with the red background gets state prop with "active" value while also not getting their backgrounds updated. When I click a cell, only that cell should have their src updated depending on the given condition.

Comment: can you create a codesandbox sample?

Comment: how do you uniquely identify each cell. I assumed that `cell.bg` will be unique and will be `bar1, bar2, bar3, bar4`. What is the value for each `cell.bg` ?  Show me all the objects for `[{bonus: "bar", bg: "bar2"}]`

Comment: I just found the solution by mysel. Turns out, if I separate each cell as a different component like `<CubeItem key={key} cell={cell }/> `  and change almost nothing in the component itself. It works as expected.

Comment: if your structure is like so `[{bonus: "bar", bg: "bar2"},{bonus: "barsomethingelse", bg: "bar1"},{bonus: "baryetanother", bg: "bar4"},{bonus: "barandanther", bg: "bar3"}]` order of course _doesn't_  matter, objects in your array can come in any order. This should work

Comment: I'm still curious, can you see my previous comment? How do the objects in the array look like. My approach should have worked, though it's good you found a solution too.

Comment: its like this: `{ bonus: "Hero attack +40", bg: "Red" },{ bonus: "Astrolabe [Star Dust] Drop +5%", bg: "Orange" },{ bonus: "Hero Health +640", bg: "Red" },{ bonus: "Fighter Hero Health +2%", bg: "White" },` depending on the bg value, src takes the image with the given color

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240258/discussion-between-sangeet-agarwal-and-enes-ceylan).